# Detecting certain columns and deleting these

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where some columns (not row) are like `["","","",""]`.

Those columns with that *characteristic* I would like to delete.

Is there an efficient way of doing that?

Comment: Hi, can you post your whole data structure so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: Dataframe? So are you using `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` it would be `del df['columnname']`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete columns where all values are empty, you first need to detect what columns contain only empty values.

So I made an example dataframe like this:

```
     empty  full  nanvalues  notempty
0              3        NaN         1
1              4        NaN         2
```

Using the apply function, we can compare entire columns to the empty string and then aggregate down with the `.all()` method.

```
empties = (df.astype(str) == "").all()
empties

empty         True
full         False
nanvalues    False
notempty     False
dtype: bool
```

Now we can drop these columns

```
empty_mask = empties.index[empties]
df.drop(empty_mask, axis=1)

   full  nanvalues  notempty
0     3        NaN         1
1     4        NaN         2
```